# What Type of Mortar do I need for a Glass Block Shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I have a glass block shower that was not installed properly. I need to know the proper way to regrout. The mortar is disintegrating. I was told I need a water-resistant mortar and to add an agent to make sure it’s waterproof. Does anyone know the proper way?

Comment: Are you going to start fresh or try and repair and reseal the existing mortar?

Comment: Glass Block Mortar is a common pre-mixed type that you will find at home stores.

Comment: "What type of *grout*..." - if anyone answers the title, @me, because I have no idea how, or with what, to *set* glass block.

Answer (score 1):

Any fortified thin set will work. I have used colored grout with add mix several times for glass block shower walls. Once the mortar is cured I then seal it the same as any tile job. There are pre mixed glass block mixes it is usually white.